# Forzar Ruta de descarga

Tags: php, sql-server, descarga

**Resumen**

Necesito  forzar la ruta al descargar un archivo, me explico cuando se descarga un archivo el navegador le dice a usted donde lo desea alojar. Lo que yo quiero es forzar esa descarga **NO** preguntar donde lo quiere descargar si no que se descargue en la ruta que yo quiero.

**EJEM**

El usuario le da click a un botón para descargar un archivo, y el archivo se alojo en C:/Documentos/Tareas/BD/ejemplo.txt

Les muestro el código de como estoy haciendo la descarga...

```
<?php 
$fileName = basename("nombredelarchivo");
    $filePath = '../BD/'.$fileName;
    if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){       
        header("Cache-Control: public");    
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");    
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");header("Content-Type: text/plain");    
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 //Read the file
        readfile($filePath);exit;
        header("../inicio.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "ERROR NO SE ENCONTRO FICHERO";
    }
?>
```

Espero me halla explicado bien,uso **PHP** y **SQL**

Comment: Por cuestiones de seguridad, los navegadores no permiten acceso a rutas en disco duro y es el usuario el que decide dónde guardar las descargas. NO puedes modificar ese comportamiento.

Comment: por seguridad del usuario los navegadores no permiten forzar una descarga en una ruta especifica de la pc del usuario.

Comment: No es posible, por algo eso se configura directamente en el navegador. Saludos.

Comment: depende de cada navegador, esta la opcion que te dan a elegir cada uno, si descargarlo directamente en la ruta una vez le des al boton o si preguntar donde descargarlo sabes? es seguridad pero por ejemplo chrome y edge de serie tienen descarga automatica sin preguntar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comentario de [@Triby](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/54039/triby) indica la respuesta a tu pregunta:

> Por cuestiones de seguridad, los navegadores no permiten acceso a
> rutas en disco duro y es el usuario el que decide dónde guardar las
> descargas. NO puedes modificar ese comportamiento.

Actualmente las politicas de seguridad que se implementan o se estan impletando en todos los sistemas, indican es que si deseas realizar un cambio en configuración o permisos, este deberá ser aprobado por el usuario.

Por ejemplo en la mayoría de los navegadores, la ruta de descarga es:

```
C:\Users\<usuario>\Downloads
```

Por cuestiones de seguridad un script no podrá acceder a tu disco, únicamente el usuario podrá definir manualmente una ruta de descarga diferente, pero no puedes forzar a que el usuario realice descargas en otra ubicación, diferente a la configurada en el navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]